# Removing Hyperlinks in Excel without effecting the colors with which it was highlighted

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a database in which there are email IDs that are marked in different colors based on the previous responses. I want to remove only hyperlinks, as whenever I am trying to work it is taking me to the respective links.

Comment: Edit your question: what is "based on the previous responses"? Include a screenshot of your spreadsheet. It looks as if you just want to remove the automatic hyperlinks in Excel. If that is the case, remove all other non-essential texts from your question. And remove your email.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you're asking is that you have cells with email addresses that are formatted both with hyperlinks and with colors indicating "previous responses" and that you want to strip out the hyperlinks without losing other formats.

Excel 2010 added a new feature to the Clear button. Select the email IDs, click on the Clear drop down, and then click on Clear Hyperlinks.

If you are using an earlier version of Excel, try the trick outlined at [this link](http://www.journalofaccountancy.com/Issues/2013/Feb/Removing-hyperlinks-in-Excel.htm): Copy the data to a new column using Paste Values. Next, delete the original data you copied (deleting the *data* and the *hyperlinks*, but not the *formatting*. Copy the data again and use Paste Values to return the data to its original location.